# react native custom framework, import is not working as it should when i try to import framework into demo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am new to react native. i have created my custom framework.
i am able to integrate and test it with demo app successfully.
however the import path i have given is not proper.
i think it should import framework with just import {} from 'frameworkname' but its not working that way.
what can be reason?
how to fix this path issue problem?

```
import ClassA from "myreact-native-framework/classes/ClassA";
import ClassB from "myreact-native-framework/classes/ClassB";
```

i think the way it should work is:

```
import {ClassA, ClassB} from "myreact-native-framework";
```

index.js looks like below:

```
import ClassA from "./classes/ClassA";
import ClassA from "./classes/ClassB";

export default { ClassA, ClassB};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your index.js like

```
export { default as ClassA } from "./classes/ClassA";
export { default as ClassB } from "./classes/ClassB";
```

If it has any issues, please ask in the comments section here